# How to pass data in a Redux store to tabBarComponent(3.x)?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I got stuck in passing the data from a redux store to the tabBarComponent.

react-navigation version : 3.x

Requirement: I store the theme color in the redux store and want to customize my bottom tab bar based the theme color.

Below is what learned from the official doc and tried

```
class TabBarComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return <BottomTabBar {...this.props} activeTintColor={this.props.theme} />;
  }
}

// const TabBarComponent = (props) => <BottomTabBar {...props} />;

let { popularPage, trendingPage, favoritePage, mePage } = homeTabs;
let dynamicTabs = { popularPage, trendingPage, favoritePage, mePage };

const homeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(dynamicTabs, {
  tabBarComponent: (props) => <TabBarComponent {...props} />,
});
const mapState = (state) => ({
  theme: state.theme.theme,
});
connect(
  mapState,
  null,
)(homeTabNavigator);
export default homeTabNavigator;
```

It seems that the react-navigation take control on the props passed to the tabBarComponent and ignores the data from the redux store. I also tried to connect the `TabBarComponent` with the store, even tried to connect `BottomTabBar` with the store. However, none of the above works.
I know we can wrap the navigator in a component and pass down the data, but in react-navigation 3.x it will create problems.
Is there a solution or work around to pass the data in the store to `tabBarComponent`?
Or is there any other way to achieve this requirement?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

finally find a solution. What I have done is to wrap the root navigator in a component,connect with redux store and pass the screenProps with my required value in the store.In this way, every child navigator has access to this attribute.Then you can use it to customize your tab bar or anything else. Hope this could help someone else.